# JavaFX: Making BorderPane's Center's contents not strech

Tags: javafx, border, borderpane, gridpane

just a quick one for you since I'm generally inexperienced in designing apps. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've got the following application, and it's obvious that it uses a `BorderPane` for its layout. I've got a `GridPane` of 5 labels and 5 `textFields` in the `Center` region, and I wanted a subtle border for it.

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, the `GridPane` utilizes the full space allocated to it in the `Center` region, and although the border gets drawn nicely, it goes all the way down to the bottom of the `Center` region (Red arrows).
**What I want it to do is finish at the blue line.**

I tried using `grid.setPrefHeight(400);`, for example, but it didn't work.

Are there any solutions other than the obvious one, to add a second container below the `GridPane` and squeeze the upper container enough?

EDIT: For reference, this is the code that creates the center area `GridPane`:

```
public GridPane addGridPaneCenter() {
GridPane grid = new GridPane();
grid.setHgap(10);
grid.setVgap(10);
grid.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 0, 10));

sihuid = new Text("SIHU ID:");
sihuid.setFont(Font.font("Inconsolata", 16));
grid.add(sihuid, 0, 1);                                           //spans from 0,1 to 1,1 (Column-Row)
sihuid_tf = new TextField();
sihuid_tf.setEditable(false);
grid.add(sihuid_tf, 1, 1);

mac = new Text("Plug MAC:");
mac.setFont(Font.font("Inconsolata", 16));
grid.add(mac, 0, 2);
mac_tf = new TextField();
mac_tf.setEditable(false);
grid.add(mac_tf, 1, 2);

loc = new Text("Location:");
loc.setFont(Font.font("Inconsolata", 16));
grid.add(loc, 0, 3);
loc_tf = new TextField();
loc_tf.setEditable(false);
grid.add(loc_tf, 1, 3);

appl = new Text("Appliance:");
appl.setFont(Font.font("Inconsolata", 16));
grid.add(appl, 0, 4);
appl_tf = new TextField();
appl_tf.setEditable(false);
grid.add(appl_tf, 1, 4);

type = new Text("Type:");
type.setFont(Font.font("Inconsolata", 16));
grid.add(type, 0, 5);
type_tf = new TextField();
type_tf.setEditable(false);
grid.add(type_tf, 1, 5);

grid.setPrefHeight(400);
grid.setStyle(
    "-fx-border-color: #b8b8ba; -fx-border-width: 1;"
    + "-fx-border-radius: 4;"
    /*+ "-fx-font: " + "Inconsolata" + ";" */
); 
return grid;
```

}

After that, there's a simple

```
GridPane grid_center = addGridPaneCenter();                             //CENTER Grid, contains info about plugs.
        border_pane.setCenter(grid_center);

    Scene scene = new Scene(border_pane, 900, 700);
    scene.setFill(Color.GHOSTWHITE);

    primaryStage.setTitle("PlugControl v0.1e");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is behaviour of `BorderPane` is by design ([ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html)):

> The top and bottom children will be resized to their preferred heights and extend the width of the borderpane. The left and right children will be resized to their preferred widths and extend the length between the top and bottom nodes. **And the center node will be resized to fill the available space in the middle.**

You should probably put the `GridPane` in an `AnchorPane` or `VBox` and put that (`AnchorPane` or `VBox`) in the center of the `BorderPane`.